# What's the best way to find a string/regex match in files recursively? (UNIX)

Tags: linux, unix, recursion, grep

I have had to do this several times, usually when trying to find in what files a variable or a function is used.

I remember using xargs with grep in the past to do this, but I am wondering if there are any easier ways.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
grep -r REGEX .
```

Replace `.` with whatever directory you want to search from.

Comment: Since you ask for "the best" way, I think you should not have accepted this answer, but the one by Chas. This is not the best answer because `-r` is not portable. The best answer is the one that's portable, deals with funny characters in file names and does only create a handful of processes in the worst case. This would be Chas' `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep pattern`. Completely POSIX and as bullet-proof as it gets.

Comment: @Jens: Since you like to be pedantic, 1. `xargs -0` wasn't portable for a very long time, and 2. Chas's, not Chas' (people's names are never considered plural).

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/621/01/ educate yourself my friend, *"James' hat is also acceptable."*

Comment: @A.J. Must I pull out Strunk and White? http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk.html#1

Answer (score 19):

The portable method* of doing this is

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep pattern
```

`-print0` tells find to use ASCII nuls as the separator and `-0` tells xargs the same thing.  If you don't use them you will get errors on files and directories that contain spaces in their names.

* as opposed to grep -r, grep -R, or grep --recursive which only work on some machines.

Comment: How do you protect your regular expression from the shell?

Comment: @FelipeAlvarez Just quoting fixes most of the problem: `grep "f.*o"`.  The only thing that should expand in a string is stuff following a `$`, so escape the `$` if necessary, but I can't think of a valid pattern for grep that would have stuff following a `$` (grep works on lines and `$` means end of line).

Comment: What happens to shell special characters After shell removes your quotes then passed it to xargs? How will that affect grep after that?

Comment: The command execute by xargs doesn't receive shell expansion.  It is a straight up `fork`/`exec` deal.  You can see this with `echo "foo*" '$foo' | xargs perl -le 'print "[$_]" for @ARGV'`.

Answer (score 9):

This is one of the cases for which I've started using **ack** (http://petdance.com/ack/) in lieu of **grep**. From the site, you can get instructions to install it as a Perl CPAN component, or you can get a self-contained version that can be installed without dealing with dependencies.

Besides the fact that it defaults to recursive searching, it allows you to use Perl-strength regular expressions, use regex's to choose files to search, etc. It has an impressive list of options. I recommend visiting the site and checking it out. I've found it extremely easy to use, and there are tips for integrating it with vi(m), emacs, and even TextMate if you use that.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for a string match, use

```
fgrep -r pattern .
```

which is faster than using grep.
More about the subject here: http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/grep.1.asp

Answer (score 3):

grep -r  if you're using GNU grep, which comes with most Linux distros.

On most UNIXes it's not installed by default so try this instead:

find . -type f | xargs grep regex

Answer (score 3):

If you use the zsh shell you can use

```
grep REGEX **/*
```

or

```
grep REGEX **/*.java
```

This can run out of steam if there are too many matching files.

The canonical way though is to use find with exec.

```
find . -name '*.java' -exec grep REGEX {} \;
```

or

```
find . -type f -exec grep REGEX {} \;
```

The 'type f' bit just means type of file and will match all files.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest changing the answer to:

`grep REGEX -r .`

The -r switch doesn't indicate regular expression.  It tells grep to recurse into the directory provided.

Comment: Putting options after positional arguments is a GNU extension. Some would say that `grep -r` is a GNU extension too, but, still, I usually make a habit of putting all options before positional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great way to find the exact expression recursively with one or more file types:

`find . \\( -name '\''*.java'\'' -o -name '\''*.xml'\'' \\) | xargs egrep`
(internal single quotes)

Where

`-name '\''*.<filetype>'\'' -o`
(again single quotes here)

is repeated in the parenthesis ( ) for how many more filetypes you want to add to your recursive search

an alias looks like this in bash

`alias fnd='find . \\( -name '\''*.java'\'' -o -name '\''*.xml'\'' \\) | xargs egrep'`