# How to read text between two particular text in unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

I want to read text between two particular words from a text file in unix shell scripting.
For example in the following:

```
"My name is Sasuke Uchiha."
```

I want to get Sasuke.

Comment: you will get better answers if you post what you have tried instead of expecting someone to write the code for you; just a tip...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the many ways it can be done:

To capture text between `"is"` and `"Uchiha"`:

```
sed -n "s/^.*is \(.*\)Uchiha.*/\1/p" inFile
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to add a "let me google that for you" link, but it seems like you're having a hard enough time as is.

[What's the best way to find a string/regex match in files recursively? (UNIX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186015/whats-the-best-way-to-find-a-string-regex-match-in-files-recursively-unix)

Take a look at that. It's similar to what you're looking for. Regex is the go to tool for matching strings and such. And Grep is the easiest way to use it from shell in unix.

Take a look at this as well: http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/regexpr.html

Comment: Actually, if you're just looking through a single file, use grep PATTERN FILENAME. In your case, you're going to type "grep Sasuke textfile.txt" in the command line