# Using regex to update a text file

Tags: regex, macos

I'm on a mac and have just started to learn about using regex. I keep a lot of notes in plain text files, and these have hashtags in them (e.g., #tag ). I'm trying to figure out how I can run a regex to find all the different hashtags in my collection of plain text files, and output the list to a text file that I can then use as a directory for my notes.

From reading answers here I'm fairly sure that regex is the right technology to be using to try to make this work, but I lack the technical vocabulary to make sense of similar questions that might be retooled for my usecase.

I really appreciate being pointed in the right direction, and I'm not afraid of doing some work for myself once I understand the questions I'm trying to ask.

Comment: Could you give us some examples of the possible input, and the expected output?

Comment: are you looking for something like this? http://regex101.com/r/aQ5oU0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186015/whats-the-best-way-to-find-a-string-regex-match-in-files-recursively-unix

Comment: Right, so the expected input is a single directory with .txt files in it, each of which has a metadata key:value at the top that looks like:

Subject: #tag1 #tag2 #tag3

The expected output is a .txt file that lists all of the tags that appear in the contents of the directory, preferably in alphabetical order:

Tag Directory

#tag1
#tag2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/\([^\( |       \)]*\)/\1\'$'\n/g' testFile.txt  | grep \# | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '        ' > dirNotes.txt
```

Given a file called **testFile.txt** with the contents:

```
This is a #test file.

#MyTest
#TestTwo #TestThree             #TestFour
```

This file has several hashtags in various locations in the file.

The command at the top does the following:

- Looks through the whole **testFile.txt** file, replacing each space or tab* with a new line **\'$'\n**
- That list of words gets passed to the **grep** that looks for the hashtag
- That list of hashtagged words gets passed to the first translate character command, dropping all spaces **tr -d ' '**
- *That* list of hashtagged words gets passed to the first translate character command, dropping all tabs* **tr -d ' '**
- Finally, the whole list is redirected into the **dirNotes.txt** file.

This results in a file with a list of hashtags, one per line:

```
#test
#MyTest
#TestTwo
#TestThree
#TestFour
```

A couple of tricks due to OSX.

- How can you put a tab on the command line?  CTRL+V TAB

In the *sed* command, you see the extra space in after the pipe (|).  That is the result of CTRL+V TAB.

In the final *tr* command, you see the same thing between the apostrophes.

As a bonus, you could wrap this in a *for* loop, looking at all the .txt files in a given directory:

```
for myFile in `ls *.txt`; do sed 's/\([^\( |  \)]*\)/\1\'$'\n/g' $myFile  | grep \# | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '     ' > $myFile.ndx; done
```

You would end up with a new list of files, some possibly zero length, with the .ndx extension.  Each .ndx file would contain the hashtags for each *parent* file.

Tested on the following:

```
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: Mac OS X 10.5.8 (9L31a)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 9.8.0
      Boot Volume: Macintosh HD
      Boot Mode: Normal
      Computer Name: myMac
      User Name: Some Dude (mang)
      Time since boot: an eon or two
```